# How to uncomment html tags using jsoup

Tags: java, html, dom, tags, jsoup

I wonder if it is possible to uncomment html tags using jsoup  for instance change :

```
<!--<p> foo bar </p>-->
```

to

```
<p> foo bar </p>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Here is one way to solve this:

1. Find all comment nodes
2. For each comment extract the data attribute
3. Insert a new node with the data after the current comment node
4. Delete the comment node

Have a look at this code:

```
 public class UncommentComments {
        public static void main(String... args) {
            String htmlIn = "<html><head></head><body>"
                    + "<!--<div> hello there </div>-->"
                    + "<div>not a comment</div>"
                    + "<!-- <h5>another comment</h5> -->" 
                    + "</body></html>";
            Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlIn);
            List<Comment> comments = findAllComments(doc);
            for (Comment comment : comments) {
                String data = comment.getData();
                comment.after(data);
                comment.remove();
            }
             System.out.println(doc.toString());
        }

        public static List<Comment> findAllComments(Document doc) {
            List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Element element : doc.getAllElements()) {
                for (Node n : element.childNodes()) {
                    if (n.nodeName().equals("#comment")){
                        comments.add((Comment)n);
                    }
                }
            }
            return Collections.unmodifiableList(comments);
        }
    }
```

Given this html document:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <!--<div> hello there </div>-->
    <div>not a comment</div>
    <!-- <h5>another comment</h5> --> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Will result in this output:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div>hello there</div>
    <div>not a comment</div> 
    <h5>another comment</h5> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Comment class , that's the key.